# Dynatree issue on tree.reload()

Tags: javascript, dynatree

Initially all my nodes are collapsed. When someone expand any node of tree,I fetch data in `onExpand` function and call `tree.reload()`.
essentially the issue is I have `onActivate` function to collapse the whole tree.at level 1.

```
onActivate : function(node) {
            node.visit(function(n) {
                n.expand(false);
            });
        },
```

so when I expand and call tree.reload(). Everything get collapsed again.
Is their a way that onReload all nodes that are expanded stay expanded.

Or Is there any way to add data when onExpand is called where i dont have to use tree.reload.

Comment: You can use a global variable in order to run the `onActivate` code only once. Please post your full code if you need more help.

Comment: Please provide the minimum code necessary to replicate the issue so we can help you further.